# Error while Creating a Relying Party Trust in ADFS

Tags: adfs, dynamics-crm-2016, adfs4.0

We are getting attached error while adding a relying party trust to ADFS. This needed to be done as our CRM Test server had to be repaired since it was not taking in new patches. We reinstalled CRM and were trying to reconfigure IFD when we are running into this issue

[**Error While Adding a Relying Party**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH1bN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While on the ADFS server, can you browse to the metadata address?

Does it result in an XML document?

I've seen this error when you have HTTP URL in the metadata. In which case, download the metadata, change to HTTPS and load as a file.

Failing that, can you add the RP manually?

Comment: Yes we can browse the metadata address and get a proper XML Document. we tried using it as a file but it gives me the same error. No we am unable to add the RP manually as well. All the 3 methods return the same error.

Comment: We performed all the steps again and this time the File option worked for us. We were able to move forward by downloading the XML and use it. Thanks @rbrayb

Answer (score 0):

We performed all the steps again and this time the File option worked for us. we were  able to move forward by downloading the XML and use it.